# Solidity - Truffle: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode NOT because of revert

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, opcode, truffle

I am working on a smart contract, and I am testing it by deploying it on truffle. While it compiles fine, when I call the train() function, I get the following error:

> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode

After reading a bit on this, I understood it is usually caused after a revert has occurred, so I tried commenting out the 2 require functions I had just to see if it would behave differently, and it did not.

Checking out  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52741259/error-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-invalid-opcode) question did not help me, or I did not see how it could.

Here is the train() function, as well as the mapping and struct type I am using in it. I should note that upon creation of a Developer, their wallet is set to 300 so I do not see how the first call of the train function by the owner could revert.

```solidity
struct Developer {
    address owner;
    string name;
    bytes32 namehash;
    bytes32[] skills;
    uint256[] skill_levels;
    uint wallet;
}

mapping (bytes32=>Developer) public developers_all;

function train(string _name, bytes32 _skill) public {
    bytes32 h = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_name));

    require(developers_all[h].owner == msg.sender, "Only the owner of the developer can train them");
    require(developers_all[h].wallet >= 150, "Insufficient funds");

    uint256 i = 0; 

    do {
        if (developers_all[h].skills[i] == _skill) {
            developers_all[h].skill_levels[i]++;
        } else if ((i == (developers_all[h].skills.length - 1)) || (developers_all[h].skills.length == 0)) {
            developers_all[h].skills.push(_skill);
            developers_all[h].skill_levels.push(1);
        }
        i++;
    } while (i < developers_all[h].skills.length);

    developers_all[h].wallet = developers_all[h].wallet - 150;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely because you are trying to access the first entry of an empty array. You're using a do while loop, and you're trying to access `developers_all[h].skills[i]` before you're checking `developers_all[h].skills.length == 0`, so it is possible that the array is empty at the first if statement in the do while.

You could rewrite the code to something like the following, to make sure you're never accessing an unassigned array slot.

```solidity
bool foundSkill = false;

for (uint i = 0; i < developers_all[h].skills.length; i++) {
    if (developers_all[h].skills[i] == _skill) {
        developers_all[h].skill_levels[i]++;
        foundSkill = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!foundSkill) {
    developers_all[h].skills.push(_skill);
    developers_all[h].skill_levels.push(1);
}
```

Do note that looping through the whole array and doing the comparisons is quite costly, and can become impossible if the array size gets too big. You might want consider changing the structure to something like:

```solidity
struct Developer {
    address owner;
    string name;
    bytes32 namehash;
    mapping(bytes32 => uint) skill_levels;
    uint wallet;
}
```

That way you could just replace the whole thing with

```solidity
developers_all[h].skill_levels[skill]++;
```

But you wouldn't be able to loop over the skills.

Comment: Thank you, this is very similar to what I ended up doing. I originally had the version with the mapping, but because later on I use a getter function, I need to be able to have all the skills returned and I have not found a way to return all elements of a mapping.

Comment: Yeah. it turns out to be true. In my code I was also getting this error, then I made a new function for getting the **size** of the array and its size was zero. Any idea on how to get the size of the array without making an extra function ????

Comment: Doesn't look like that is possible. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20812/get-array-length-without-a-getter-from-other-contract